# how to drag and drop css file in eclipse?

Tags: html, css, eclipse

I'm new to elipse php. i have used dream viewer for my php development before moving to the eclipse. So, i need to know when i drag and drop the css file into html editor, it needs to auto genarate the `<link>` tag for that css file. It worked with dream viewer. But its not working with eclipse. And, also when i need to use css classes inside html tag it needs to type the css class name.But, instead that i need to know how to config that to all the css class as suggestion for html tags, like in dream viewer and netBeans.

Comment: Both are different IDE's each have there own  features and drawbacks you can't find the features that are there in dreamviewer and vice versa.

Comment: so in eclipse can't  i do these things ?

Comment: how you configured php in eclipse have you tried creating a php project instead of a simple solo file project?

Comment: yes i have done that. Php is working that is not a metter. I can not belive that eclipse does not have these features. these are basic features in web development ..

Comment: Actually dreamwiever is a WISYWIG editor so there drag and drop will work but eclipse is different.

Comment: Which set of PHP tools in Eclipse are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Eclipse is not an IDE, it's a platform you can build IDEs (or any other application). There are several implementations for different languages. Most popular one which is actually the origin of Eclipse is Java IDE. There is also a plugin/feature for PHP development, called PDT.

DreamViewer is a specialized WYSIWYG editor for web development (mostly around HTML/CSS/Javascript) that includes support for different web scripting languages. It has some special properties as you mentioned, that can create a link element when you DnD.

What you can do is request a new feature from PDT team, that creates a link element to the dropped file inside a HTML document.

Answer (score 1):

The text DnD (Drag and Drop) feature (initially introduced by bug 11624 in 2007) has been slowly extended to various editors, as reported by the bug 231294:

Tested in EclipsePdt-2.2.0.v20100427
Verified fixed for:

- PHP files
- JS files

Still reproducible in:

1. CSS files
2. HTML files
3. XML files (source view)

So it is still "work in progress".

The relevant blocking issues are:

bug 178104: [DND] Need to revisit dnd API to allow multiple drop targets

bug 173405: Make use of IDragAndDropService (Show Votes)

bug 195655: Drag'n'drop selected text